# Update a complete JSON config file from spring cloud config

Tags: spring, git, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am currently setting up a spring cloud config server to deliver some JSON config files from a specific repository, using RabbitMQ to propagate change events to the clients.

Therefore I added a REST endpoint, which delivers all config files, based on a passed branch name:

```
@RestController
public class RPConfigsEndpoint {

   @Autowired
   private JGitEnvironmentRepository repository;

   private File[] files;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/myConfigs")
   public File[] getList(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "master") String branch) {
        //load/refresh the branch
        repository.refresh(branch);
        try {
            FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
            Repository repo = builder.setGitDir(repository.getBasedir()).readEnvironment().findGitDir().build();
            //only return JSON files
            files = repo.getDirectory().listFiles((file, s) -> {
                return s.toLowerCase().endsWith(".json");
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return files;
    }
}
```

As expected, I get all the files as plain text files... so far so good.

**Now my question:**

If I modify one of these files and trigger the `'/monitor'` endpoint on the server, it generates a RefreshEvent as expected:

```
.c.s.e.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository : Fetched for remote master and found 1 updates
o.s.cloud.bus.event.RefreshListener      : Received remote refresh request. Keys refreshed []
```

This event is sent, as the server notices that the commit ID has changed.
The delta of refreshed keys is empty, as it only looks for environment properties (in .yml or .properties files).

Is there a way to reload the whole config file on the client side as it would be done with single properties? Do I therefore need to adapt the change notification?

With my current approach, I would have to reload the whole branch (40 files) instead of reloading only the modified file...

I found a similar question from 2016 on [github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/578), without finding the answer.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

**Update**

`repository.findOne(...)` and `repository.refresh(...)` are not thread safe, which must be garanteed in cloud environment, as the service can be contacted by different apps at the same time.

Possible solutions:

- 'synchronize' the concerned method call(s)
- avoid listing up all the files and request single plain text files, as it works out of the box.