# Print Observable object

Tags: observable, rx-java

How can I print the Observable of JaxRS programming, to debug the response of third party.

```
RollOutCalculatorClientImpl.debugLogger.debug("{}", ()->"--------------->Hitting Account Details SAPI with URL :"
         + webTarget.getUri().toString());
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54943397/update-a-complete-json-config-file-from-spring-cloud-config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Return Type = Observable < Map < String, Object >>

final RxWebTarget < RxObservableInvoker > webTarget = this.rxClient.target(
        this.endpointResolver.getServiceEndpoint(userRequestContext, Constants.SAPI_ROLL_OUT_CALCULATOR_ENDPOINT))
    .resolveTemplates(requestParamValues);

RollOutCalculatorClientImpl.debugLogger.debug("{}", ()->"--------------->Hitting Account Details SAPI with URL :"
     + webTarget.getUri().toString());

userRequestContext.getTracker().stopRequestTime();
Observable < Response > reponse = webTarget.request().headers(userRequestContext.getHeaders()).rx().get().single();
returnreponse.map(sapiResponse->{
    Map < String,
    Object > respo = ResponseParser.parse(sapiResponse, userRequestContext);
    System.out.println("Sumeet----->" + respo);
    returnrespo;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter; 

ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).